# Running script as cron job doesnt show data.

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I am unable to display ip address whenever i run my .sh script as a cronjob. Whenever I execute the script using ./myscript.sh I am able to get the ip address being displayed in the html file. Please let me know whats wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
container_id=$(docker ps -a | cut -c 1-20)
container_id_ele=($container_id)
container_status=$(docker ps -a | cut -c 80-100)
container_status_ele=($container_status)
last_run=`date`
hostip=`ifconfig eno1 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $2}'|sed    's/addr://'`
cat > /home/docker/index.html <<EOF
<html>
 <body>
   <table border=1>
   <tr>
         <td>Host</td>
         <td>Container Id</td>
         <td>Status</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> $hostip </td>
     <td> ${container_id_ele[2]}</td>
     <td> ${container_status_ele[1]} ${container_status_ele[2]}   ${container_status_ele[3]} </td>
 </tr>
   </table>
Note : Status will be updated every 60 seconds <br/>
Last run :$last_run
 </body>
</html>
EOF
`docker cp /home/docker/index.html tomcat:/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice script. Here is little rewrite.

```
#!/bin/bash
export myhostip=`hostname -I`
echo $myhostip
cat > ./index.html <<EOF
<html>
        <body>
                <h1>$myhostip</h1>
        </body>
</html>
EOF
```

It's working.